# Subscript operator accepts variable length arguments of variable type?

Tags: c++

Does the `[]` operator accept variable length arguments or variable types? Is this behavior similar to `va_args` or is the last parameter always passed implicitly?

Can someone explain why the following doesn't error during compilation? (tested in VS2010)

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::map<int, std::string> KeyValueMap;
    typedef std::vector<int> IntList;

    IntList l(10);
    int r = l[l, "C", 1];

    KeyValueMap m;
    m[m, 1, "D", 2];

    int* i = new int[10];
    int x = i["a", i, 1];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comma (`,`) is an operator which evaluates all arguments and returns the last one.

`int x = i["a", i, 1];` is basically equivalent to `int x = i[1];`.

Comment: Only in this situation? Can you give me an example of where you could use this? Or where else that `,` evaluation happens?

Comment: @Aesthete in all situations where it is an operator (for example, it is a separator when you pass in arguments to a function). You could use this anywhere, but with little to no gain. For example, `if ( foo(), bar() ) { }` will call both `foo` and `bar`, but enter the brackets only if `bar` is true.

Comment: @Aesthete : search "comma operator" on stackoverflow, the 4-5 first results contain very good explanations with examples.